# still reachable block in valgrind output for vector of std threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, valgrind

I have the below code that when run under valgrind shows that still says some block is reachable. Although the code does not have any explicit leaks. 
Why is this happening.

Please help?

valgrind trace is

```
==5059== 32 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 1
==5059==    at 0x4C2C20C: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:334)
==5059==    by 0x402A67: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::thread>::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) (new_allocator.h:104)
==5059==    by 0x402986: std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::thread> >::allocate(std::allocator<std::thread>&, unsigned long) (alloc_traits.h:416)
==5059==    by 0x40280F: std::_Vector_base<std::thread, std::allocator<std::thread> >::_M_allocate(unsigned long) (stl_vector.h:170)
==5059==    by 0x402493: void std::vector<std::thread, std::allocator<std::thread> >::_M_emplace_back_aux<std::thread>(std::thread&&) (vector.tcc:412)
==5059==    by 0x402008: void std::vector<std::thread, std::allocator<std::thread> >::emplace_back<std::thread>(std::thread&&) (vector.tcc:101)
==5059==    by 0x40188F: std::vector<std::thread, std::allocator<std::thread> >::push_back(std::thread&&) (stl_vector.h:933)
==5059==    by 0x4012D0: main (t3.cpp:25)

==5059== LEAK SUMMARY:
==5059==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5059==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5059==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5059==    still reachable: 32 bytes in 1 blocks
==5059==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5059==
```

The code is below.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include<mutex>
#include<thread>

using namespace std;

std::mutex g_mutex;

void dosomework(const int& id)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(g_mutex);
    cout << "I am doing some work in thread id = " << id << endl;
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    threads.reserve(3);

    for(unsigned int i=0; i<3; ++i)
        threads.push_back(std::thread(dosomework,i));

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10));

    for(auto& t : threads)
    {

        if(t.joinable())
        {
            cout << "joining the thread" << endl;
            t.join();
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "thread is not joinable" << endl;
        }
    }

    exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is because `exit(0)` is called instead of `return 0` from your `main()`.

When `return` is called in `main()`, destructors will be called for locally scoped objects whereas if `exit()` is called then that is not the case!

Comment: Yes basics basics!! i missed that one. bad idea to use exit , should almost always avoid it.